# what's the value type of the value of request.POST in django?

Tags: django

This is from print(request.POST)

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['2Tg4HgJ07qksb3hPUDWSQYueYOjYOkQcmzll9fnjbJ0GZHkWHdM8DtYqZB4uv3Fv'], 'username': ['boycececil'], 'password': ['password']}>
```

This is from print(request.POST.get('username'))

```
boycececil
```

So as you can see, list (from one of the values of QueryDict)-> string(from the get function), that's magic! Isn't it?

So, somebody know what's going on?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects `a dictionary-like class customized to deal with multiple values for the same key`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.__getitem__ `Returns the value for the given key. If the key has more than one value, it returns the last value`

Comment: FYI, in python you can use type() to see the type of the object, and it's who's subclass. In this case, print type(request.POST)   and it print "django.http.request.QueryDict" and you can check django document to see what is the "QueryDict" and if there is any polymorphism for this class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What the value type of the value of `request.POST` in django?

The type is `django.http.request.QueryDict`

> So as you can see, `list -> string`, that's magic! Isn't it?

No, it isn't magic.  This is just the [documented behavior](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) of `QueryDict`:

> *"`QueryDict.__getitem__(key)`*
>
> *Returns the value for the given key. If the key has more than one value, it returns the last value. ..."*

Note: if you want all values for a key, you can call `getlist(key)` on the `QueryDict`.

---

> So, the request.POST is a subclass of the dictionary but not a raw dictionary.

It is a subclass of the django `MultiValueDict` class which is a subclass of `dict`.

> When I call get(key) to the Querydict it return the last value of the list. Sounds like the get method in Querydict overwrite the get method in the raw dictionary.

Yes  ... that is what the `__getitem__` method does.

> By the way, I wonder why we need multiple value for one key.

It is because HTTP allows multiple values for a given parameter in a request.  So if multiple values can be provided, django need to be able to make them available via the `HttpRequest.POST` object.

But since this is an unusual case, they decided to just give your code one value for each parameter ... unless it specifically asks for them all.  Django is being helpful.

Comment: So, the request.POST is a subclass of the dictionary but not a raw dictionary. When I call get(key) to the Querydict  it renturn the last value of the list. Sounds like the get method in Querydict overwrite the get method in the raw dictionary. By the way, I wonder why we need multiple value for one key.... I tried, if your template have more than one <input> with the same 'name' attribute, then the list did receive contain more than one value and only return the last one. I guess I can use this in case like "I need user to input the password twice when signing up",  newbie's guess,thx anyway!